# A tag class not working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, tags

I have an A tag I'm trying to add a class to. This is probably really simple stuff but I've never done this before.

```
<a class="button" href="landscaping.html">Find out more about our landscape design services</a>
```

And the CSS:

```
a .button{
color:#7cc242;
font-family: 'PTSansNarrowBold';
font-size:18px;
margin-top: 7px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
text-align:right;
text-decoration:none;
display: inline-block;
zoom:1;
*display:inline;
padding-right:30px;
background:url(images/more-btn.png) no-repeat top right;}
```

Nothing seems to be working, I'm just getting the standard blue. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There shouldn't be a space! Please change:

```
a .button{
```

to:

```
a.button{
```

Check out fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VhaNQ/

Comment: Thank you so much! D'oh - I knew it'd be one of those silly problems. Thanks for helping me see the blindingly obvious!

Answer (score 7):

What you say in your CSS is "I want all **children** with class `button`, of all `a` tags to use the next CSS rules".

What you need to say is "I want tag `a` with class `button` to use the next CSS rules".

This is achieved by writing the next CSS:

```
a.button{
  color:#7cc242;
  font-family: 'PTSansNarrowBold';
  font-size:18px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align:right;
  text-decoration:none;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom:1;
  *display:inline;
  padding-right:30px;
  background:url(images/more-btn.png) no-repeat top right;
}
```

Note that **there is no space** between `a` and `.button`

Spaces between tags/classes/ids means "children of element".

Good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

Remove Space from `a .button` like this `a.button` or use simply `.button`